# Custom Is64BitOperatingSystem preprocessor directive

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, .net-standard, preprocessor-directive

We can add custom preprocessor directives for [Platform Conditional Compilation in .NET Core](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2018/11/05/platform-conditional-compilation-in-net-core/) like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsWindows Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true'">true</IsWindows>
    <IsOSX Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))' == 'true'">true</IsOSX>
    <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsWindows)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Windows</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsOSX)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>OSX</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsLinux)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Linux</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I've tested, it's working fine.

Now I want to detect whether or not I'm on a 64 bits operating system. Here is my `.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Is64BitOperatingSystem Condition="'$([System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)' == 'true'">true</Is64BitOperatingSystem>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Is64BitOperatingSystem)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Is64BitOperatingSystem</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

However when I run this code, my first `if...else` is working as expected but not my `Is64BitOperatingSystem` preprocessor directive

```cs
if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    Console.WriteLine(64);
else
    Console.WriteLine(32);

#if Is64BitOperatingSystem
    Console.WriteLine(64);
#else
   Console.WriteLine(32);
#endif
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't spot where's the mistake in my code.

Thank you

## EDIT

To add more details about this, I included this code in a .NET Standard library that is called by a .NET Core project.

I want my library to detect the current architecture it's running on (**or has been compiled for**) so I can do something like this

```cs
#if Is64BitOperatingSystem
    [DllImport(@"Resources/HIDAPI/x64/hidapi")]
#else
    [DllImport(@"Resources/HIDAPI/x32/hidapi")]
#endif
```

Before debugging, Visual Studio obviously compiles my application so at this stage checking the architecture using `System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` or a preprocessor directive should give the same results but it's not. I'm on a 64 bits machine and my preprocessor directive tells me I'm on a 32 bits architecture even if I change `AnyCPU` to `x64` in Visual Studio Configuration Manager

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313450/1203116) is Windows specific and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8861895/1203116) too because the solution is to call the `SetDllDirectory` function from `kernel32.dll`

But I want my code to be able to run on Linux.

## EDIT 2:

For the sake of sharing a minimal sample here I actually removed the faulty part of my code.

It looks like this gives the expected result:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Is64BitOperatingSystem Condition="'$([System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)' == 'true'">true</Is64BitOperatingSystem>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Is64BitOperatingSystem)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Is64BitOperatingSystem</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But this gives a faulty behavior:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Is64BitOperatingSystem Condition="'$([System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)' == 'true'">true</Is64BitOperatingSystem>
    <IsWindows Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true'">true</IsWindows>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Is64BitOperatingSystem)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Is64BitOperatingSystem</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsWindows)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Windows</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If anybody could explain me that? 
I don't understand why adding the `IsWindows` condition is responsible for a different behavior on the `Is64BitOperatingSystem` preprocessor directive

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say it's not working. What are you actually doing to try this out? `if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)` and `#if Is64BitOperatingSystem` mean very different things here. The first would depend on where the code is running. The second would depend on where the code is _compiled_.

Comment: So that is not actually your .csproj file, what you posted is corrupt.

Comment: @HansPassant what I posted is not corrupt, the first code block is a quote from the blog post I linked because it's a good practice on SO. I wrote `Here is my .csproj` for the 2nd code block

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL You have excess closing `</PropertyGroup>` tag in your `csproj` file. Also I can't reproduce your issue, the `Is64BitOperatingSystem` works as expected

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Oops that was just a copy paste issue. Also now both my .NET Standard library and my .NET Core project have `<Platforms>x64</Platforms>`, I recompiled my code but I still get the issue

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why. I think my question is well enough written with some code samples

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL I'm not downvoting, but your issue isn't reproducible

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski sorry, this comment wasn't specifically for you but for whoever is downvoting. I don't know what else I can provide to reproduce this issue. My .NET Core project is an almost empty console application at this point. Nothing special in its `.csproj`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I edited my question. I actually found the source of the faulty behavior but I really couldn't tell why. It doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Why are you trying to go about things this way rather than just having different build configurations in your .sln/.csproj? As I said, this would make it so that the compilation result would be dependent on the the bitness of the operating system where the code is built, meaning you'd have to have separate build machines for the 32-bit and 64-bit builds. If you used separate build configurations, you could build both versions on the same machine.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL Please, have a look at my answer. The reason of the faulty behavior is the way of setting the `DefineConstants`. You'll need to set them only once using semicolon separated list of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to thank both [JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59336549/1203116) and [Pavel Anikhouski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339550/1203116) for their answers. Although they were very useful, they were actually both not complete so I thought I should write myself another answer with all the necessary information.

I created a [sample project on Github](https://github.com/jmevel/DetectArchitectureSample) so you can play with it. Here are the explanations

Adding a `Conditional Compilation Symbol` in the Visual Studio Configuration Manager actually adds a `DefineConstants` node in the `.csproj` behind the hood.

It doesn't need any new MsBuild variable declaration like I did in my question. It just uses an existing `Platform` variable which already exists.

Moreover the way I used in my question seems incompatible with a `dotnet publish` command

With a `.csproj` like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86;linux-x64;linux-arm64;linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Is64BitOperatingSystem Condition="'$([System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)' == 'true'">true</Is64BitOperatingSystem>
    <Platforms>x64;x86;arm64;arm86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Is64BitOperatingSystem)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);Is64BitOperatingSystem</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Running the command

```sh
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release
```

would return the following error

> DetectArchitectureSample.csproj(7,29): error MSB4185: The function "Is64BitOperatingSystem" on type "System.Environment" is not available for execution as an MSBuild property function.

We actually don't need to add an extra `Is64BitOperatingSystem` variable. All we need is to reuse the existing `Platform` variable like this

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86;linux-x64;linux-arm64;linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Platforms>x64;x86;arm64;arm86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Platform)=='x64' Or $(Platform)=='arm64'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);Is64Bit</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target BeforeTargets="Build" Name="test">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="$(DefineConstants)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Then specify the `Platform` we want during the publish

```sh
dotnet publish -r linux-arm64 -c Release /p:Platform=arm64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

The output of this command would return a line like that

> TRACE;Is64Bit;RELEASE;NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP3_1

Finally in our code we can load the correct unmanaged DLL depending of the platform the program has been compiled for

```cs
#if Is64Bit
    [DllImport(@"Resources/HIDAPI/x64/hidapi")]
#else
    [DllImport(@"Resources/HIDAPI/x32/hidapi")]
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it isn't working in last edit is that conditional constants in `DefineConstants` can't be defined separately, the value of this property is semicolon separated list of values and should be defined by adding an new constant to existing list (many thanks to @Orace for the help)

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsWindows)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);Windows</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Is64BitOperatingSystem)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);Is64BitOperatingSystem</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can pass these values to `msbuild` command line as well.

The following code will work as expected

```cs
#if Windows
    Console.WriteLine("built in Windows!");
#endif

#if Is64BitOperatingSystem
    Console.WriteLine("built on x64");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("built on x86");
#endif
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? "running on x64" : "running on x86");
```

It will display:

```
built in Windows! 
built on x64
running on x64
```

You can add a `Linux` constant on the same way as well.

The following msbuild target will help you to check which constants are defined in a project

```
<Target BeforeTargets="Build" Name="test">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="$(DefineConstants)"/>
</Target>
```

In my test app it's showing `TRACE;Windows;Is64BitOperatingSystem;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP2_1`

Comment: There are workarounds to avoid to completely override`defineconstants` content. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112684/edit-the-defineconstants-in-csproj-file

Comment: Maybe just add `$(DefineConstants);...` in `DefineConstants`

Comment: @Orace thank you, it makes sense. Will check and update an answer later

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL does it solve your question? Do you need more details/explanation?

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski thanks a lot for your answer. Even though it helped me a lot, it didn't fully solve my question. I wrote myself an answer

Answer (score 2):

> I want my library to detect the current architecture it's running on (or has been compiled for) so I can do something like this

If this is your requirement, then I think you are going about things the wrong way. The approach you are trying to use will make the library dependent on the architecture *where it was built* and nothing else.

Compilation directives, as the name implies, take effect at compile time. They have no effect at *runtime*. If you want to have different `[DllImport]`s for different architectures, you will need different builds. And typically the way to go about that is to have different build configurations.

In Configuration Manager, create two separate solution platforms, with corresponding project platforms:

[image: Configuration Manager Build Configurations]

In your Project properties -> Build tab, specify a conditional compilation directive for one of the two:

[image: Project Properties]

In your code, use the compilation symbol:

```
#if Is64Bit
    [DllImport(@"Resources/HIDAPI/x64/hidapi")]
#else
    [DllImport(@"Resources/HIDAPI/x32/hidapi")]
#endif
```

Comment: I must say even after reading your answer several times I'm still confused about it. `The approach you are trying to use will make the library dependent on the architecture where it was built and nothing else` but then you suggest me to have several `build configurations` instead... Are you saying with my way, even if I try compiling for the 32 bits architecture it would still consider `Is64BitOperatingSystem` as `true` because I compiled it on a 64 bits machine? Could you please explain a bit more the difference between a `DefineConstants` and a `Conditional compilation symbol`? Thanks

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL _"Are you saying with my way, even if I try compiling for the 32 bits architecture it would still consider Is64BitOperatingSystem as true because I compiled it on a 64 bits machine?"_ Yes, AFAIK `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` returns the bitness of the actual OS, not the bitness of the assembly. Feel free to try that out for yourself and verify, but that is what I found. So in order to use the approach you're trying, you would have to actually _build_ your program on a 32-bit OS in order to do your 32-bit build. With the above, you can build both on one machine.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL _"Could you please explain a bit more the difference between a DefineConstants and a Conditional compilation symbol?"_ They are essentially the same thing. "Conditional compilation symbol" is just the name given to them in the project properties pane.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this helped me a lot like [Pavel answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339550/1203116). I upvoted but your explanation using the Visual Studio interface wasn't clear enough IMO. I wrote my own answer to clarify everything with some `.csproj` examples